# Armazenar o tamanho da string de um array

Tags: php, json, array

Bom dia pessoal,
Estou tentando pegar o tamanho de uma string de um array armazenar em uma variável para que eu possa depois utilizar um "if".
Utilizei o var_dump() onde consigo saber o tamanho da string mas não sei como faço para comparar esse valor, esses dados serão enviados para um JSON e exibidos em uma DataTables (Jquery), alguém poderia me dar uma luz sobre isso ou alguma outra alternativa ?
Obrigado.

```
$sql = "SELECT q_num, time_start, from_userpart, ts_servicing FROM callcent_queuecalls WHERE q_num = '8010' AND ts_servicing = '00:00:00' ORDER BY time_start DESC";

$resultset = pg_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:" . pg_errormessage($conn));
$data = array();

    while ($rows = pg_fetch_array($resultset)) {
          $array2 = $rows[2];
          $meuarray = explode(' ', $array2);
          foreach($meuarray as $valor) {
              $imprime = strlen($valor);
                  echo $imprime."</br>";
          }
    }
```

**SOLUÇÃO**

```
$array2 = $rows[2];
$intlen = strlen($array2);
if (($intlen === 8) || ($intlen === 9) || ($intlen === 11) || ($intlen ===        12)) {


    $meuarray = explode(" ", $array2);
    foreach ($meuarray as $valor) {
        $str = str_split($valor);
        if (($str[0] === '1') || ($str[0] === '2') || ($str[0] === '7')) {
            $exlui = array_shift($str);
        }
        $implode = implode("", $str);


        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($implode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Já fez alguma parte do código? Pode mostrar a estrutura do array, ou exemplificar como ele seria?

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer acabei de editar a pergunta com parte do cod.

Comment: tente utilizar $imprime = strlen($valor) e veja qual será o resultado do echo $imprime.

Comment: @FelipeG. já tentei utilizar ele me retorna o valor da string correto até ai OK, agora como faço para pegar cada valor desse e conseguir comparar eles depois nisso que estou travado. A funçao mb_strlen não me retorna nada.

Comment: Tem ideia de como deve ficar o array final?

Comment: Então, quando utilizo:   '  $array2 = $rows[2]; print_r($array2); ' parece que me retorna apenas um arrray. resultado: 21298806969321298806969321298806969311299..., ele concatena todos os dados e quando utilizo var_dump ele me retorna: string(12) "212988069693" string(12) "212988069693" string(12) "212988069693"...

Comment: vc quer um array só com o tamanho da string? ou quer um array com o valor e o tamanho?

Comment: vou tentar explicar melhor, tenho o campo telefone onde ele tem vários formatos preciso padronizar eles, para eu saber qual editar precisaria pegar o tamanho do campo telefone ex: tamanho 12, se ele tiver 12 caracteres excluir o primeiro caractere e jogar uma mascara e retornar o telefone formatado para o JSON exibir em minha DataTable.

Comment: Aquele `explode()` o que ele faz? o mais simples se tudo estiver certo é contar os caracteres direto no sql e despachar o json. Coloquei um exemplo pra vc entender a saida: https://repl.it/repls/ThunderousNauticalRingtailedlemur

Comment: @rray no caso o `explode()` está transformando meu array em string, se eu retirar o mesmo e passar apenas `foreach()` ele não me retorna nada. Vou dar uma olhada em seu exemplo, obrigado.

Comment: @rray bom, quando utilizo `mb_strlen()` ele me retorna um erro `GET 
http://localhost:8080/projeto1/lostCall/data.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 39 ms]` então deixei apenas `strlen()`, também não consegui retornar apenas o campo telefone do Array, tive que passar a query inteira, o resultado obtido foi esse [link](https://pastebin.com/BMh4ZBv5) notei que ele também está duplicando os valores, o tamanho ficaria armazenado na variável $item ?

Comment: Consegui resolver pessoal, vou **editar** a pergunta com a solução, agradeço a todos, se alguém tiver alguma opinião sobre o cod estou aceitando.